# incomplete gamma function in python?

Tags: python, scipy

the `scipy.special.gammainc` can not take negative values for the first argument. Are there any other implementations that could in python? I can do a manual integration for sure but I'd like to know if there are good alternatives that already exist.

```
Correct result: 1 - Gamma[-1,1] = 0.85

Use Scipy: scipy.special.gammainc(-1, 1) = 0
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I typically reach for [mpmath](http://code.google.com/p/mpmath/) whenever I need special functions and I'm not too concerned about performance.  (Although its performance in many cases is pretty good anyway.)

For example:

```
>>> import mpmath
>>> mpmath.gammainc(-1,1)
mpf('0.14849550677592205')
>>> 1-mpmath.gammainc(-1,1)
mpf('0.85150449322407795')
>>> mpmath.mp.dps = 50 # arbitrary precision!
>>> 1-mpmath.gammainc(-1,1)
mpf('0.85150449322407795208164000529866078158523616237514084')
```

Comment: thanks, I did a brief search online but failed to find a standalone solution. Guess this is one of the few occasions that I install an extra package for a single functionality ;-)

Comment: what does the 'mpf' stand for?

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue and ended up using the recurrence relations for the function when a<0.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Properties

Note also that the scipy functions gammainc and gammaincc give the regularized forms Gamma(a,x)/Gamma(a)

Answer (score 1):

Still an issue in 2021, and they still haven't improved this in scipy.  Especially it is frustrating that `scipy` does not even provide unregularised versions of the upper and lower incomplete Gamma functions.   I also ended up using `mpmath`, which uses its own data type (here `mpf` for mpmath floating - which supports arbitrary precision).  In order to cook up something quick for the upper and lower incomplete Gamma function that works with `numpy` arrays, and that behaves like one would expect from evaluating those integrals I came up with the following:

```py
import numpy as np
from mpmath import gammainc

"""
In both functinos below a is a float and z is a numpy.array.
"""

def gammainc_up(a,z):
    return np.asarray([gammainc(a, zi, regularized=False)
                       for zi in z]).astype(float)

def gammainc_low(a,z):
    return np.asarray([gamainc(a, 0, zi, regularized=False)
                       for zi in z]).astype(float)
```

Note again, this is for the un-regularised functions (Eq. 8.2.1 and 8.2.2 in the [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.2)), the regularised functions (Eq. 8.2.3 and 8.2.4) can be obtined in `mpmath` by setting the keyword `regularized=True`.