# vectorize incomplete gamma function with negative arguments

Tags: python, scipy, mpmath

I am using mpmaths incomplete gamma function with negative z, and complex integration bounds a, b. See documentation: [docs](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/expintegrals.html)

This can't be done with scipy's incomplete gamma function. I benched marked mpmath against Mathematica and got the same results. Unfortunately the mpmaths function can only evaluate a single value at a time, which means I have to loop over the array which contains the values of z,a,b.

I believe vectorization is hard because for negative z one has to evaluate the integral recursively in parts (see this post and the respective wiki: [incomplete gamma function in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542780/incomplete-gamma-function-in-python))

Does anyone know a module that can handle this? Or if there is no such thing if it is even possible?

So in essence:

```
from mpmath import gammainc
values = np.random.normal(0, 100, 1000) + 1j*np.random.normal(0, 100, 1000)
res_mp = np.array([gammainc(cc, 4, 10) for cc in values])
```

I've actually implemented something that I believe works to some extend:

```
import numpy as np

def new_quad_routine(func, c, a, b,x_list, w_list):
    c_1 = (b-a)/2.0
    c_2 = (b+a)/2.0

    eval_points = c_1*x_list+c_2             
    func_evals = func(eval_points, c)                              
    return c_1 * np.sum(func_evals * w_list[:,np.newaxis], axis=0)

def new_quad_gauss_7(func, c, a, b):   
    """
    integrates a complex function with bounds, a, b with an array of arguments c
    call for instance with the gamma function:
    new_quad_gauss_7(gamma_integrator, 4, 10)

    """
    x_gauss = np.array([-0.949107912342759, -0.741531185599394, -0.405845151377397, 0, 0.405845151377397, 0.741531185599394, 0.949107912342759])            
    w_gauss = np.array([0.129484966168870, 0.279705391489277, 0.381830050505119, 0.417959183673469, 0.381830050505119, 0.279705391489277,0.129484966168870])
    return new_quad_routine(func, c, a, b, x_gauss, w_gauss)

def gamma_integrator(t, c):
    return t[:, np.newaxis]**c*np.exp(-t[:,np.newaxis])

def gammainc_function(c, a, b):
    if type(c) is not np.ndarray:
        raise ValueError("Need a numpy array for function argument!")
    return new_quad_gauss_7(gamma_integrator, c-1, a, b)
```

This is based on the [numerical integrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965583/use-scipy-integrate-quad-to-integrate-complex-numbers) in this post.

It is pretty fast:

```
values=np.repeat(-2+3j-1, 100)
In [143]: %timeit new_quad_gauss_7(gamma_integrator, 4, 10, values)
107 µs ± 574 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [144]: %timeit [gammainc(cc, 4, 10) for cc in values]
224 ms ± 2.86 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I don't know how good it is though. So the question slightly changes to how can I benchmark and or improve this? Furthermore, this seems to work for fixed bounds. However, I do not know how one would implement an integral with infinite bounds on either end.

Comment: What is `s` ? Here is the signature of the function `mpmath.gammainc(z, a=0, b=inf, regularized=False)`

Comment: Sorry `s` is based on the wikipedia. here is of course `z`

Comment: Could you add an example of what you want exactly to do?

Comment: Do you really mean *complex* bounds of integration?   None of the examples mention that possibility, and it’s not well defined for an integrand with poles (*i.e.*, for z<1).

Comment: Have you found some other implementations (C,C++, or Fortran), which does exactly what you want? 
It would be quite straight forward to write a small Python wrapper.

Comment: @DavisHerring yes I fear the bounds are complex. mathmp can deal with that, however I have no deeper understanding of why it can. I just crosschecked mathematica and the mpmath function and they give consistent results

Comment: So your idea is to basically step back and do the numerical integration yourself?  For these exponential integrals this is a bit tricky, and there is specialist literature out there - I don't think this is a question well suited for stack-overflow.